# QuoteValidationRuleInterface does not exist Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, class-not-found

I am suddenly getting below error in my working Magento 2.2.6 project.

> Class Magento\Quote\Model\ValidationRules\QuoteValidationRuleInterface does not exist

This file does not exist in my project from the beginning and it was working without any error.

Still i tried with removing **Magento_Quote** from **vendor** directory and reinstalling with `composer install` command but that new **Quote** module also does not include **QuoteValidationRuleInterface** file.

What can be the issue?